# is there a standard C function to get abs of a Double variable

Tags: c

Is there a standard C function that would take a double and return its absolute value as a double? It is not that difficult to write one, but if it exists why bother. There is int abs(int x), but why isn't there `double abs_d(double x)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is `fabs`.  `fabsf` for floats, `fabs` for doubles.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fabs.html

Comment: And `fabsl` for `long double`. (BTW, that link is to the POSIX standard; the definitive description is in the ISO C standard.)